# Change the value of a property of some data, but tableview doesn't update

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

For a very simple table demo of TornadoFX, I just want to show some `users` in a view, and changes the names of them when clicking on a `change` button. But the problem is the modified data is not shown in table.

The main code is as following:

```
class User2(id: Int, name: String) {
    val idProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(id)
    var id by idProperty

    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
    var name by nameProperty
}

val data2 = listOf(User2(111, "AAA"), User2(222, "BBB"), User2(333, "CCC")).observable()

vbox {
    tableview(data2) {
        column("id", User2::id)
        column("name", User2::name).minWidth(200)
    }
    button("Modify data with type of User2").setOnAction {
        data2.forEach { it.name += " changed!" }
    }
}
```

Instead, if I define the `User2` as following (also changed the class name to `User1`):

```
class User1(id: Int, name: String) {
    val id = SimpleIntegerProperty(id)
    val name = SimpleStringProperty(name)
}
```

Everything is working well.

I can't find why the first one is not working (as the code is most copied form [the official guide](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part1/11.%20Editing%20Models%20and%20Validation.md#a-typical-use-case))

Update:

A complete small demo to represent this question: https://github.com/javafx-demos/tornadofx-table-property-change-issue-demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this issue is caused by confusing naming :-)

When refactoring User2 and renaming some fields it becomes evident that you were using the `String` and `Int` fields instead of the `StringProperty` and `IntegerProperty`, which obviously don't support binding.

If `User2` looks like following:

```
class User2(id: Int, name: String) {
    val idProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(id)
    var myId by idProperty

    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
    var myName by nameProperty
}
```

And the code changing it like following:

```
vbox {
    tableview(data2) {
        column("myId", User2::myId)
        column("myName", User2::nameProperty).minWidth(200)
    }
    button("Modify data with type of User2").setOnAction {
        data2.forEach { it.myName += " changed!" }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine. As you can see before you were changing only the `Int` and `String` fields which doesn't lead to any updates.

Comment: Thanks for making it work, but I found the real change is you use `User2::nameProperty` instead of `User2::name`. It's then working even if the property `id` and `name` keeps unchanged

Comment: And I also found in the official guid mentioned in the question actually uses `column("Name", Person::nameProperty)` too, not `column("Name", Person::name)`, so the cause is found. I think there are two similar properties(like `id`, `idProperty`) in the `User2` makes it easy to use the wrong one and hard to find it bug, since the code is compilable.

Answer (score 1):

For observable properties you must reference the property, not the getter. If you reference the getter you will see data, but it will never update. Go back to the way you defined the User object first, then reference User::idProperty and User::nameProperty for the columns.

Comment: Thanks, Edvin. Just found the first way to define `User2` makes it easy to use wrong property by mistake and hard to figure it out, since they are similar, and the code is compilable, and it works for most of cases.